# How can I set up xboard with an engine in Linux?

Tags: software, stockfish, linux

I'm trying to use xboard in Fedora and have only been able to get it to work under very specific circumstances.

I installed it through my package manager and installed Stockfish as well. Without going into excessive detail, gnuchess (which comes with comes with xboard) will only perform a correct analysis if I load a pgn file or make a sequence of moves from the starting position. If I attempt to edit a position and analyze it, it gives me an error saying the 'edit' command isn't implemented and it begins to analyze the starting position.

I can't get Stockfish to work with xboard at all. As I understand it, Stockfish is a UCI engine and requires a translator to work with xboard. Until recently this was supposed to be Polyglot, but in the past couple of years UCI2WB has become the favored translator (neither one is included in Fedora's repository). I cloned and built uci2wb and launched xboard with `xboard -adapterCommand="./uci2wb" -fcp stockfish -fUCI` from the UCI2WB directory, but when I attempted to analyze a position it gave me an error: `xboard: Error writing to first chess program: Broken pipe`.

How can I get xboard to work with either of these engines?